# How to make gvfs mount fat/vfat drives with 8.3 names set to lowercase on automatic mount?

Tags: mount, vfat, gvfs

Use case: when USB flash or SD card is plugged in, the filesystem is mounted. It is mounted by `gvfsd`. But if the filesystem contains files in legacy 8.3 format (like digital cameras often save file names on fs), then the file names are automatically transformed to upper case. So, the files on filesystem appears like FILENAME.JPG.

How to make `gvfs` automatically mount FAT/VFAT drives so that the file names would appear in lowercase even if they are saved in the 8.3 format?

Answer (score 0):

Add `shortname=lower` to your mount options.

Or at least, that's what worked for me.